# Driver Intel Wireless-AC 9560 suddenly stop because of Failed to start INIT ucode: -110

Tags: drivers, server, 20.04, kernel, iwlwifi

I am using Wireless-AC 9560 of NUC8i3BEK on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

After working few days properly, the wireless card does not work. It seems that it does not load the firmware (9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode) suddenly.

I got the dump from `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`.

```
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.768630] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.768631] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 0
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994792] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994794] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994799] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994805] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994807] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 20
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 21
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    7.994814] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 28
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    8.005186] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.4e1ceb39.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Oct  3 16:52:54  kernel: [    8.148364] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x312
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 9df08086 00100406 02800030 00800010 4ac10004 00000040 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 0000010b
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000040: 00928010 10000ec0 00100c10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000080: 800f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343770] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000100: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343783] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 16410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 18c89002 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000010 0c000005 00000312 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.343933] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591396] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591398] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | IML/ROM data1
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591413] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B6D349E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DA67CF6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0E937B87 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18F8D750 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFC15867 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE86663DA | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.591493] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.781845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.793595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.806598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 0
Oct  3 16:52:58  kernel: [   13.809549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x312
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   18.975404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   18.975428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   18.975455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   18.975467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223903] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223922] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223934] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | IML/ROM data1
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223940] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223943] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B6D349E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DA67CF6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0E937B87 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223962] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18F8D750 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223965] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFC15867 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223968] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE86663DA | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223971] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.223981] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.224020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.414168] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.425604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.438600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 1
Oct  3 16:53:04  kernel: [   19.441551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x312
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.607228] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.607263] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.607303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.607328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855772] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | IML/ROM error/state
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855805] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | IML/ROM data1
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B6D349E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DA67CF6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0E937B87 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18F8D750 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFC15867 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE86663DA | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Oct  3 16:53:09  kernel: [   24.855890] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Oct  3 16:53:10  kernel: [   25.038900] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
Oct  3 16:53:10  kernel: [   25.051347] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
Oct  3 16:53:10  kernel: [   25.064449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: retry init count 2
```

This is the basic info.

```
[user@iot ~]# uname -r
5.14.0-1052-oem
```

```
[user@iot ~]# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0
       description: Network controller
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:16 memory:404ac10000-404ac13fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 30
       serial: 1c:69:7a:06:bf:81
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.14.0-1052-oem duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 ip=192.168.0.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:129 memory:c0a00000-c0a1ffff
```

I appreciate for some advices.
Below is the progress.

After removing the backport and downgrading from 5.14.0-1052-oem to 5.6.0-1056-oem, the problem is still not fixed.

This is the log.

```
[user@iot ~/]# dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    8.031147] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.4e1ceb39.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.113786] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[   13.337578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   13.337586] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   13.337588] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   13.337676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 9df08086 00100406 02800030 00800010 4ac10004 00000040 00000000 00000000
[   13.337678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 0000010b
[   13.337680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000040: 00928010 10000ec0 00100c10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000060: 00000000 00080812 00000405 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000080: 800f0011 00002000 00003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000a0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000c0: 00000000 00000000 c823d001 0d000008 00804005 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 000000e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000100: 14c00000 ff000000 000000ff 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000120: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000140: 00000000 00000000 00000000 16410018 00000000 0001001e 00481e1f 00000000
[   13.337700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   13.337725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 18c89008 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   13.337727] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000010 0c000005 00000312 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
[   13.337734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   13.337742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   13.337744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   13.586160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   13.586176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   13.586179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6B6D349E | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   13.586182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   13.586185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0DA67CF6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   13.586188] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   13.586191] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0E937B87 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   13.586194] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18F8D750 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   13.586197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFFC15867 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   13.586200] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE86663DA | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   13.586202] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   13.586207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   13.586213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   13.586251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   13.586298] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   13.586527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   13.598927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Finally I removed OEM kernel, But it is still not working.

```
[user@iot ~]#  uname -r
5.4.0-126-generic
```

The pc is working more than 100 units as IoT currently.

I have searched and tried solutions but all to no solve.

Could anyone please help this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139622/discussion-on-question-by-k-usami-driver-intel-wireless-ac-9560-suddenly-stop-be).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Finally I resolved the problem. However it is not best solution.
The way is only physical power off and on.
I guess it causes hardware problem.

See this discussion if you want to know more.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139622/discussion-on-question-by-k-usami-driver-intel-wireless-ac-9560-suddenly-stop-be